# JFrame always on top not working after changing the screen resolution

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, screen-resolution

Q1) I have a JFrame which i want to stay on top always, but after changing the screen resolution programmatically, the setAlwaysOnTop() doesn't take effect.

Q2) Why does it display 3x of the same screen resolution (Height, Weight,Rate, BitDepth)?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisplayModeChanger1 extends JFrame {

private static GraphicsDevice device;
private static JButton BtnChangeResolution = new JButton("Dummy Btn");
private static boolean isFullScreenSupported = false;
static JFrame f = new JFrame();
static int vcHight = 0;     
static int vcWeight = 0;
static int vcRate = 0;
static int vcBitDepth = 0;

public DisplayModeChanger1(final GraphicsDevice device) {
    DisplayModeChanger1.device = device;


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    DisplayModeChanger1 changer = new DisplayModeChanger1(defaultScreen);
    DisplayMode dm = null;

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice display = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    DisplayMode[] availableModes = display.getDisplayModes();

    for (DisplayMode DV : availableModes) {

        vcHight = DV.getWidth();
        vcWeight = DV.getHeight();
        vcRate = DV.getRefreshRate();
        vcBitDepth = DV.getBitDepth();  

        //change screen resolution if desired resolution found
        if(DV.getWidth() == 800 && DV.getHeight() == 600){
            vcHight = DV.getWidth();
            vcWeight = DV.getHeight();
            vcRate = DV.getRefreshRate();
            vcBitDepth = DV.getBitDepth(); 

            //Assigning Display Mode 
            dm = new DisplayMode(vcHight, vcWeight, vcBitDepth, vcRate);

            System.out.println(vcHight);
            System.out.println(vcWeight);
            System.out.println(vcRate);
            System.out.println(vcBitDepth);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------\n");

        }                                 
    }    

    isFullScreenSupported = device.isFullScreenSupported();       
    if (isFullScreenSupported) {
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        device.setFullScreenWindow(f);
        f.validate();
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    try {

         device.setDisplayMode(dm);
         f.setSize(new Dimension(dm.getWidth(), dm.getHeight()));  
         System.out.println("Screen height resolution was changed to [ " + dm.getHeight() + " ]");
         System.out.println("Screen width  resolution was changed to [ " +dm.getWidth() + " ]");
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.setResizable(false);
         f.add(BtnChangeResolution);
         //f.validate();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "ERROR--->" + e2);
    }      

   }
}
```